# In SFML, how do I apply a transformation without the scaling factor?

Tags: c++, sfml

I am creating a UI system in SFML based on the [Object Hierarchy Example](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/graphics-transform.php) on the wiki. I have a TextBox node that contains an sf::Text object that I want to be displayed. My issue is that when I increase the scale factor of the sf::Text object, it zooms into the text making it appear pixely. It would make much more sense to just increase the font size, but I cannot figure out how to apply the transformations of the parent node minus the scale factor to prevent the zooming in effect. I have a very limited understanding of transformation matrices, which I gather are what applies the transformation. Any advice on how to proceed is appreciated.

Comment: I'd use a different font size. Just set `fontsizeNew= sftextScale * fontsizeOriginal` where `sftextScale` is the scale you apply to the text.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237369/given-this-transformation-matrix-how-do-i-decompose-it-into-translation-rotati) which helped me separate the scale factor from the transform matrix. For those with a similar problem, here is the solution I came to:

```
const float* mat = states.transform.getMatrix();
float temp[16];
std::copy(mat, mat + 16, temp); // mat has 16 members, hence mat + 16 is the last member
float scalex = sqrtf((temp[0] * temp[0]) + (temp[1] * temp[1]));
float scaley = sqrtf((temp[4] * temp[4]) + (temp[5] * temp[5]));
// Remove scale from the final transform
sf::Transform textState(
    temp[0] / scalex, temp[1] / scaley, temp[12], 
    temp[4] / scalex, temp[5] / scaley, temp[13],
    0.f, 0.f, 1.f
    );
```